# Vulkan support incomplete issue Ubuntu Studio 20.10

Tags: wine, vulkan

Ubuntu Studio 20.10.
I need help with getting Vulkan to work. Also have a font error opening wine notepad.
Any help and suggestions is much appreciated.

```
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
```

Terminal info for Vulkan:

```
vulkaninfo
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
ERROR: [Loader Message] Code 0 : /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
WARNING: lavapipe is not a conformant vulkan implementation, testing use only.
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.141
```

Terminal Info loading lutris

```
lutris
2021-03-11 17:55:21,702: Initializing lutris
2021-03-11 17:55:23,770: Downloading DXVK releases to /home/bob/.local/share/lutris/runtime/dxvk/dxvk_versions.json
2021-03-11 17:55:23,772: Runtime updated. Initialization complete.
2021-03-11 17:55:23,773: Lutris 0.5.8.3
2021-03-11 17:55:23,773: Running Intel Open Source Technology Center Mesa driver 21.1.0 on Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2) (0xa16)
2021-03-11 17:55:23,774: GPU: 8086:0A16 17AA:3978 (i915 drivers)
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
```

Terminal Info Loading wine notepad

```
wine notepad
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0034:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0064:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
006c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
MESA-INTEL: warning: Haswell Vulkan support is incomplete
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
002c:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
00f4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
00f4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
00f4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.
00f4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f4:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0024:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
```

Comment: Hello, do you understand what we have to do? I have the same problem.